# Can I meet a transit passenger airside at DOH if we are departing on the same flight?

Tags: transit, airports, airport-security, qatar

This is my first flight so I am not sure about how flying works. Basically my friend is transiting at Doha (DOH) from the UK to go to Singapore, I am also booked on same flight with him, as I live in Qatar, and I will go with him to Singapore. My friend has 5 hours' transit time.

My question is, can I meet my friend once he arrives at the airport and stay inside the airport, and can we both go together to the next flight?

Comment: Once you have passed immigration, you can meet him anywhere inside the airport.

Answer (score 4):

AIUI (no personal experiance, based on what I have read online)

You will need to check in and go through exit immigration and security. Your friend would normally go through transfer security. Once you both reach the international departure area you should be able to meet up.

A complication may be if you have checked baggage. Many airlines restrict how early you can check your bags, so you may have to wait for baggage check to open for your flight before you can check your bags and proceed through immigration and security to join your fried.

Comment: Ohhh.. i only have hang luggage. So hopefully i can get in quickly  i hope